# Why do JPA EntityManager queries always return NullPointerException?

Tags: java, jpa, jndi, tomcat8

I'm trying to implement the Java Persistence API (JPA) in my Java 8 web project. Running on Tomcat 8.

The persistence.jar that I am using is from EclipseLink

I've set up my persistence.xml configuration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="myDatabase" transaction-type="JTA">
      <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myDB</non-jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

My JNDI resource is defined in context.xml and I've tested that it can be queried as a regular DataSource within another class, so the database connection is functioning correctly.

I've followed the *Java EE 7: The Big Picture*, 'Chapter 12: Modern Memories: The Java Persistence API' by Dr. Danny Coward but cannot get the any of em.find, em.createNamedQuery, etc. to work.

My data access using entity manager: [stub]

```
@Singleton
public class JPAPersonDataImpl {
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManager em;

    private Person getPersonById(int id) {
        return (em.find(Person.class, id));
    }
}
```

My data access if using entity manager factory: [stub]

```
@Singleton
public class JPAPersonDataImpl {
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "myDatabase")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private Person getPersonById(int id) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        try {
            return (em.find(Person.class, id));
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

My Person.class [stub]

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(
        {
                @NamedQuery(
                        name = "Person.getAllPersons",
                        query = "select m from Person m"
                ),
                @NamedQuery(
                        name = "Person.getPersonByUsername",
                        query = "select m from Person m where m.userName = :userName"
                ),
                @NamedQuery(
                        name = "Person.getLastPersonCreated",
                        query = "select m from Person m order by m.PersonId desc"
                ),
                @NamedQuery(
                        name = "Person.getUsernames",
                        query = "select m.userName from Person m"
                )
        }
)
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PersonId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private Date joined;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(int id, String userName, String firstName, String surname, Date joined) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.joined = joined;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public Date getJoinedDate() {
        return this.joined;
    }
}
```

Example with executing NamedQueries (I've tried all of TypedQuery, Query and also creating a Native query - all return a NullPointer):

```
@Singleton
public class JPAPersonDataImpl {
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "myDatabase")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    // This can also be modifed to use EntityManager instead of EntityManagerFactory
    private boolean userNameIsInUse(String username) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        try {
            TypedQuery<Person> queryUserNames = em.createNamedQuery("Person.getUsernames", Person.class);
            List queryResultList = queryUserNames.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
            return (matchInList(queryResultList, username));
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Why would any access attempt (query, persist, remove, find, etc.) return a NullPointerException when there is a valid JNDI resource? Is there a simple test that I could do to determine if EntityManager is set up correctly?

Comment: I'm guessing you're instantiating and not injecting your `JPAPersonDataImpl`.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could share the full, stacktrace of the excpetion.

Comment: I think @chrylis has the answer here. How are you handling the creation of your `JPAPersonDataImpl` instance? You should be injecting it with the `@EJB` annotation which gives the container (Tomcat) control. You should *not* be instantiating it yourself like this `JPAPersonDataImpl bean = new JPAPersonDataImpl()`.

Comment: Hi @chrylis and ~matt - I think you have the right diagnosis for me. I'm completely new to Java EE - so I'm downloading Apache OpenEJB and will be making my bean an Enterprise Bean to see if that works. Which I guess leads me to another question - why doesn't the IntelliJ compiler handle annotation problems in a way that is more visible to the developer? Maybe I need to set my project structure up properly for EJB!

Comment: Tomcat is not an EJB container(its a Servlet container). Annotating with @EJB doesnot work with Tomcat. You need Web servers like GlassFish, JBoss (they provide EJB container).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're diving into the complete formal Java EE system? My personal experience is that it's frequently used as a cafeteria-style pick-the-relevant-components menu, and if you have the option I personally prefer Spring as a container (and implementation of about a quarter of EE, with integrations for most of the rest).

Comment: You mean "why have i not injected the EntityManager correctly"?

Answer (score 1):

You should understand how **Entitymanagers are managed**.
i) Container-managed
ii) Application-managed.
In your case , since Tomcat is not a J2EE container, look at Application managed EM.
 Check out this. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm.